# Cannot implicitly convert type 'Model.RouteListModel' to 'string'

Tags: c#, import

I am facing this error:

> `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Model.RouteListModel' to 'string`'

ReportModel class:

```
  public class RouteGroup
  {
      public IGrouping<string, RouteImportModel> Data { get; set; }
  }

  public class RouteImportModel
  {
        ..
        ..
  }

  public class RouteListModel
  {
       ..
       ..
  }
```

The Service class has the following method which saves data imported from the excel file into various tables of the database:

```
public RouteListModel GetRouteSaveObj(RouteGroup model, User userInfo)
{
            var temp = model.Data.ToList();
            var areaTemp = temp.Select(x => x.AREA).Distinct().ToList();
            var AreaQuery = $"SELECT AREA_CODE FROM DIST_AREA_MASTER WHERE UPPER(AREA_NAME) IN (UPPER(TRIM('{String.Join("')),UPPER(TRIM('", areaTemp)}')))";

            var result = new RouteListModel
            {
                ROUTE_NAME = temp[0].ROUTE_NAME,
                ROUTE_TYPE = temp[0].ROUTE_TYPE,
                AREA_CODE = _objectEntity.SqlQuery<string>(AreaQuery).ToList()
            };

            var entities = new List<RouteEntityModel>();
            var sn = 1;
            foreach (var item in temp)
            {
                var query = "";
                if (item.ENTITY_TYPE == "D")
                    query = $"SELECT TO_CHAR(CUSTOMER_CODE) FROM SA_CUSTOMER_SETUP WHERE CUSTOMER_EDESC = '{item.ENTITY}'  AND COMPANY_CODE='{userInfo.company_code}' AND DELETED_FLAG='N'";
                if (item.ENTITY_TYPE == "R")
                    query = $"SELECT TO_CHAR(RESELLER_CODE) FROM DIST_RESELLER_MASTER WHERE RESELLER_NAME = '{item.ENTITY}' AND COMPANY_CODE='{userInfo.company_code}' AND DELETED_FLAG='N'";
                if (item.ENTITY_TYPE == "P")
                    query = $"";
                if (item.ENTITY_TYPE == "H")
                    query = $"SELECT TO_CHAR(CODE) FROM BRD_OTHER_ENTITY WHERE DESCRIPTION = '{item.ENTITY}' AND COMPANY_CODE = '{userInfo.company_code}' AND DELETED_FLAG = 'N'";

                entities.Add(new RouteEntityModel
                {
                    ENTITY_Code = _objectEntity.SqlQuery<string>(query).FirstOrDefault(),
                    ENTITY_TYPE = item.ENTITY_TYPE,
                    ORDER_NO = sn.ToString()
                });
                sn++;
            }
            result.RouteEntityModel = entities;
            return result;
}
```

Finally the controller has following method which imports the excel file and binds the data with model

```
public JsonResult ImportRouteData(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
            Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
            try
            {
                if (file == null || file.ContentLength == 0)
                {

                    return Json(new { TYPE = "error", MESSAGE = "Empty File" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (file.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || file.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
                    {
                        string paths = Server.MapPath("~/DistributionExcel/Branding/" + file.FileName);
                        string strMappath = "~/DistributionExcel/Branding/";
                        string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(strMappath), file.FileName);
                        if (!Directory.Exists(strMappath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(strMappath));
                        }
                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                            System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                        file.SaveAs(path);
                        string sheetName = "Sheet 1";
                        string filepath = paths;
                        var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(filepath);
                        var worksheetNames = excel.GetWorksheetNames();
                        if (worksheetNames.ElementAt(0) != sheetName)
                        {
                            return Json(new { TYPE = "warning", MESSAGE = "Sheet name mismatched" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                        }

                        var listItems = (from a in excel.Worksheet<RouteImportModel>(sheetName)
                                         where !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a.ROUTE_NAME)
                                         select a).ToList();
                        var groupedData = listItems.GroupBy(x => x.ROUTE_NAME);
                        var result = string.Empty;
                        var inserted = 0;
                        foreach (var item in groupedData)
                        {
                            var group = new RouteGroup
                            {
                                Data = item
                            };
                            result = _service.GetRouteSaveObj(group, _workContext.CurrentUserinformation);***ERROR IN THIS LINE AS CANNOT IMPLICITLY CONVERT TYPE ROUTELISTMODEL TO STRING***
                            if (result == "success")
                                inserted++;
                        }

                        return Json(new { TYPE = "success", MESSAGE = inserted + " items successfully inserted" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json(new { TYPE = "error", MESSAGE = "File format error" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            finally
            {
                application.Quit();
            }
}
```

Comment: which line shows the errror

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line below.

```
result = _service.GetRouteSaveObj(group, _workContext.CurrentUserinformation);
if (result == "success") //THIS LINE IS THE PROBLEM
    inserted++;
```

`GetRouteSaveObj` return object of type `RouteListModel`  so that compare it to string `"success"` causing the compiler to try to convert `result` to `string` implicitly

I don't know how do you determine if it fails or success so this all I could help.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your are trying to compare `RouteListModel` with `success`.Have a look at return type of service method `GetRouteSaveObj` .

As per your service method ,you should check for `null` instead of comparing it with string.

Simply convert your following code

```
 result = _service.GetRouteSaveObj(group, _workContext.CurrentUserinformation);***ERROR IN THIS LINE AS CANNOT IMPLICITLY CONVERT TYPE ROUTELISTMODEL TO STRING***
 if (result == "success")
     inserted++;
```

to

```
 result = _service.GetRouteSaveObj(group, _workContext.CurrentUserinformation);***ERROR IN THIS LINE AS CANNOT IMPLICITLY CONVERT TYPE ROUTELISTMODEL TO STRING***
 if (result!=null)
    inserted++;
```